# Hide specific words if not enough space available (css only)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a simple navigation where some parts of the navigation items are hidden depending on the available space:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px
}
ul {
  margin: 0 30px 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
li:first-child{
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
li a {
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
.important {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href=#>
        <span class=important>my</span>
        <span>elem</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=#>
        <span>my</span>
        <span class=important>elem</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=#>
        <span class=important>my</span>
        <span>elem</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=#>
        <span>my</span>
        <span class="important">2nd</span>
        <span>elem</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=#>
        <span>longerfirst</span>
        <span class="important">elem</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I successfully made some words disappear with using a fixed height and `overflow:hidden` on the `a` tag.

Now I'm looking for a solution to keep the red words (`.important`) visible and hide the others. Is there a way to do this?

If the word on the invisible line is longer than the visible one, the visible has too much whitespace, is there also a solution to this?

With Javascript it would be fairly easy, but I'm looking for a CSS only solution.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86qjexz3/

Comment: I think the `text-overflow` property is exactly for that. You can specify various kinds of behavior for truncating the text, although not everything is supported in every browser. See Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow